# Not able to see maven downloaded jar inner dependencies in maven local repository

Tags: java, maven-3, citrus-framework

I have a maven jar in which i need to modify some part of code so I downloaded source code from git it consists inner dependecy shown below.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.consol.citrus</groupId>
  <artifactId>citrus-test-support</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

after importing source code to eclipse I found error like missing dependency(missing dependency shown above). by using artifact id I searched in maven repository but am not able to find it. but when I mention maven jar(source code as maven dependency in my project) it showing the missing dependency in dependency heirachy. I dont know where I am missing. could some one help on this please

here is the screen shot of eclipse error error : missing artifact id [image]

here is screen shot of  dependency in transtive dependency :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `citrus-test-support` module is an development internal module so it is not published to Maven central as you have already mentioned.

So in order to have it available on your local machine for development you need to build it from scratch. As you have already cloned the sources from git you may build everything locally with:

```
mvn install
```

This will build all artifacts locally including the internal development modules such as `citrus-test-support`

Answer (score 0):

I think below would serve your purpose:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.consol.citrus/citrus-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.consol.citrus</groupId>
    <artifactId>citrus-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: added screen shot please check. eclipse is showing the missing jar in dependency hierarchy when I went in to pom.xml of jar(source code of thejar that I want to change) when I added to my project.